# Dark green patches on aloe vera

Tags: aloe

I’ve had this aloe vera plant for about seven years. Three years ago it became too big to keep indoors so I moved it outside to a shady spot. But each winter, I bring it back inside.
It’s warm again so it’s time to get the aloe back out. I moved it outside three days ago after I was confident that there wouldn’t be any more frost. And these dark patches cropped up.

The patches have more than doubled in size since they appeared yesterday. There were no patches before it went outside. When inside, I would water it once in about 4-6 weeks. It got a good soak the first day it was out; more than what I’d normally give it.

Is it sun damage? Was that last water too much of a flood? Maybe I need to repot again? Could it be these dark patches are healthy? Someone please help![image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes aloes turn color as temps drop and go back up. Mine has dark green patches on it, but is, and has, and I hope it continues to do well. Aloes can even turn very light pink or opaque pinky orange hue when temps hit 20 degrees, so it may be change in temp in light. Do some research or call a horticulturalist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; if could include suggestions regarding light, temperature, watering, and if '20 degrees Farenheit', and if 'change in temp in night', could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the Tour, and browse through the Help center to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!